# How add new session with session name on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies

I have problem with add new session with custom name in wordpress,

I try put this in `function.php` and it's work :

```
function myStartSession() {
    session_destroy();
    session_name('my_session');
    session_start();
}
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
```

But when put same code in other file like single.php not work anymore

I try put only my function in `functions.php` and put `add_action` in `single.php` but same problem, not work

How i can create session with custom name and call when i need it

Comment: in which page you are checking session? single page or some otherpage?

Comment: search.php and single.php only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code to this:

```
function myStartSession() {
  session_destroy();
  session_name('my_session');
  session_start();
}
add_action('my_action_name', 'myStartSession');
```

Then within your template files, like single.php as you mentioned, if you want to call the function add:

```
 do_action('my_action_name');
```

Comment: i try it but not work, and when put `do_action` in function.php it's work, i don't know why it's not work outside function.php, any idea sir

Comment: Where are you placing it within single.php? Can we see some code?

Comment: i try it in single.php and page.php and search.php all files except functions.php not work, and my code like i put in top, i want only make new session right now but can't

Comment: sorry for delay, i'm post my comment and screenshot in other page lol, screenshot here : ibb.co/bXW9v9 i'm using default files not edit anything

Comment: more info : i'm added `do_action` in `header.php` and it's work but in `single.php` not work, i'm try change theme to default wordpress theme `twentyseventeen` but same problem in `single.php` / EDITED : i found problem where, when put do_action before `get_header();` it's work but after header not work, what problem in header !!

Comment: Can you send an image of your functions.php myStartSession() also?

Comment: i found problem where, when put do_action before `get_header();` it's work but after header not work, what problem in header !!

Comment: but i still have problem, i want call it on middle page single.php but can't, i want know why header not let him to work

Comment: Ok, delete do_action('my_action_name'); and delete add_action('my_action_name', 'myStartSession'); To call it within your template file, simply call the function within the template. So within single.php add myStartSession();

Comment: i do like you say but not work after get_header(); I have another information for you if you can help, when delete wp_head(); inside header it's work but lose page style

Answer (score 0):

no need to destroy the session, you just need to check if It's not started and start it

```
function myStartSession() {
   if( ! session_id() ) {
     session_start();
   }
   $_SESSION['custom_name'] = 'value';
}
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
```

Comment: not work, i found something maybe will help, when remove wp_head(); from header it's work, so something from head break session for me, any sulotion to detect it ?

Comment: replace 'init' with 'wp_head'